# Handing multiple button clicks in struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have 

    `<s:submit name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
    <s:submit name="ShowRecords" value="ShowRecords"/>
    <s:submit name="FilterRecords" value="FilterRecords"/>`

on my jsp page. I am supposed to write an action class to get all params and process them. I want to know how can I handle different button clicks ?

I tried following solutions:

1.boolean Submit, ShowRecords, FilterRecords;

2.private String buttonName;

and put getters and setters for them but all I get is false or null values.
There are some blogs telling to use path attribute in action tag but I get error that "path should be used for an type of action type" (something similar)

Is there any way to get request object in my action class?

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a hidden field and javascript/JQuery code to identify which button has been clicked. When user clicks on button you can set the hidden field value to appropriate name of the button and then submit the for.

e.g.

```
<s:form action="/test.do">
<input type="hidden" name="buttonName" id="buttonName" value=""/>
<s:submit name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('buttonName').value='submit';"/>
    <s:submit name="ShowRecords" value="ShowRecords" onclick="document.getElementById('buttonName').value='ShowRecords';"/>
    <s:submit name="FilterRecords" value="FilterRecords" onclick="document.getElementById('buttonName').value='FilterRecords';"/>
</s:form>
```